# Set Marker above LatLng center

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

If I set market in map:

```
.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(lat, lang))
                            .title("Title")                         
                            .snippet("Description")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .fromResource(R.drawable.dot1)))
```

The markers are intended to be arrows, then the marker is not put up position,  it is pointing position.

I use a marker that is a circle and need to be put right above the position, not pointing.

How I can do to make a marker is placed just above the position and not up pointing?

Comment: mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {   
                mMap.clear();               
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(arg0.target));
        }
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.anchor(0.5f, 0.5f) solved problem.

```
.add(map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(lat, lang))
                            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                            .title("Title")                         
                            .snippet("Description")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .fromResource(R.drawable.dot1))))
```